# Is there a way to diff a line from different files?

Tags: linux, diff

I'm currently doing some consolidation of i18n files. In some cases I have duplicate keys across multiple files, and I want to figure out if I can remove one of the duplicates.

Here's an example:

```
config/locales/en-primary.yml:  language_key: 'lorem ipsum'
config/locales/en-secondary.yml:  language_key: 'lorem ipsum'
```

Now obviously these are the same, which is easy to see in english, but things get tougher against other languages, and when the lines get longer. My current command to produce these lines is as follows:

```
grep language_key config/locales/en-*.yml
```

Is there a way to pipe those two lines into `diff` to compare them against each other? I can guarantee only two results for each grep'ing if that makes things easier.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know about all instances where a key is duplicated, and it doesn't matter whether the values are the same (because you will have to take manual action in any case)? Or do you want to be told only of the case where the values match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just the two files:

```
diff <(grep 'language_key' config/locales/en-primary.yml) <(grep 'language_key' config/locales/en-secondary.yml)
```

Comment: In `bash` or any other shell with process substitution using this form.

Answer (score 0):

Variation of DopeGhoti's answer (note about support for process substitution applies here as well), this here is with a side-by-side view of differing lines:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(grep 'language_key' config/locales/en-primary.yml) <(grep 'language_key' config/locales/en-secondary.yml)
```